# Xcode error while archiving file to upload to app store connect

Tags: ios, xcode

[This is the my info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NifV5.png)I am getting this error while archiving my code.

> ERROR ITMS-90771: "Missing Info.plist value. The Info.plist key 'BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers' must contain a list of identifiers used to submit and handle tasks when 'UIBackgroundModes' has a value of 'processing'. For more information, refer to the Information Property List Key Reference at [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html.%22)

I have tried all the solutions on stackoverflow to add a key to the plist file, but nothings working.

Comment: You should at least show the contents of your `Info.plist`

Comment: HI, I added the info.plist file

Comment: Do not post codes as screenshot.